# Multiple Pivot table in singe worksheet with Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, openpyxl

I want to generate multiple Pivot tables and move them to single excel worksheet.

I am able to generate Pivot table but once i am coping to single working sheet only last one is visible all rest are lost.
I am using below code:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("columncondtition.xlsx") as writer:
    pivot.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Pivot Report")
    pivot1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Pivot Report")
```

How this can be done?

Comment: How working change sheetname like `pivot1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Pivot Report1")` ?

Comment: Than it will create the Pivot in new sheet. I want all the Pivot in singe worksheet. Hope this explain